# Referencing state for loop rendered elements in react

Tags: reactjs

See my code pen here:

https://codepen.io/kiwideejay/pen/zEyZdj?editors=1111

The key line is here:

```
  componentWillMount() {        

        let items = this.props.objs.map((v,i) =>{       
            return <li 
                      className = {(this.state.i === i) ? "selected" : ""} > 
                         {v} - {this.state.i} - {i}
                   </li> 
        }); 

        this.setState({items:items});
      }
```

It's pretty straight forward - I want to conditionally set the class of each of the elements, depending on the value of `this.state.i`. However - I'm guessing the way I've generated these dom elements isn't react responsive.

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Why you don't use [this way - docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#embedding-map-in-jsx) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting state in componentWillMount is not a good practice like it states in [react docs.](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount).

> `componentWillMount()` is invoked immediately before mounting occurs.
>   It is called before `render()`, therefore setting state synchronously
>   in this method will not trigger a re-rendering. Avoid introducing any
>   side-effects or subscriptions in this method.

Rather then setting the items to state and then rendering you can just map in render function or you can separate the function and just call it in render. If you still would like to have the items in state you should use `componentDidMount` life-cycle method.

The way you set the `className` is just fine if you ask me.

**Example**

```
renderListItems = () => {
  return this.props.objs.map((v,i) => {       
           return ( 
             <li className={(this.state.i === i) ? "selected" : ""}> 
               {`${v} - ${this.state.i} - ${i}`}
             </li>
           ) 
         }); 
}

render() {
  return(
    <div>
      <ul>
        {this.renderListItems()}
      </ul>
    <div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use componentWillUpdate() instead of componentWillMount(). componentWillMount() is a callback that only gets called once before render() so setting the state in this method will not trigger a re-render.

Comment: Hmm, I don't really want to rerender all the items each time though.

Comment: @dwjohnston Check out this codepen then - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YrdZdz?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you don't need to set the items to variable before the render function. Just render them in the `render()` method's return statement.

```
  render() {                
    return <div>

      <ul> 
        {this.props.objs.map((v,i) =>{       
              return <li 
                           className = {(this.state.i === i) ? "selected" : ""} > 
                                  {v} - {this.state.i} - {i} 
                     </li> 
        })}
      </ul>

     //snip
```

Codepen here: https://codepen.io/kiwideejay/pen/boOqQg?editors=1111